# Unable to get the configuration file WcmApiConfig.properties

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-workplace

I have an issue with **FileNet-p8**: 
All simply, I do not have access to a WorkFlow already designed. I have always a popup asking me to authenticate , I use the same Login/psw to access to the Workplace. But always I get the same message :

> **Unable to get the configuration file WcmApiConfig.properties**

I'm workin with the **IBM JVM 1.6** and the **Firefox** browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In our environment, you must use IE in order to avoid that error message.  We have not been able to get FireFox to work with WorkplaceXT or PCC.

Even when launching PCC from ACCPE we need to use IE.

If you see the login screen, don't even bother with your credentials.  It simply will not work.